# Orientdb Http api with ssl

Tags: orientdb

How can i use orientdb(community) http api with ssl.

i was applying this procedures. browser get this error "ssl sertificate not trusted "
https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Using-SSL-with-OrientDB.html

version 3.0.6 
system : centos.

```
        <sockets>
        <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerTLSSocketFactory" name="ssl">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                <parameter value="my password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                <parameter value="my password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
            </parameters>
        </socket>
        <socket implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.OServerTLSSocketFactory" name="https">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="false" name="network.ssl.clientAuth"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.keyStore"/>
                <parameter value="my password" name="network.ssl.keyStorePassword"/>
                <parameter value="config/cert/orientdb.ks" name="network.ssl.trustStore"/>
                <parameter value="my password" name="network.ssl.trustStorePassword"/>
            </parameters>
        </socket>
    </sockets>
    <protocols>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary" name="binary"/>
        <protocol implementation="com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.http.ONetworkProtocolHttpDb" name="http"/>

    </protocols>
    <listeners>
        <listener protocol="binary" socket="default"   port-range="2424-2430" ip-address="0.0.0.0"/>
        <listener protocol="http"   socket="https"   port-range="2434-2440" ip-address="0.0.0.0">
```

Comment: Are the certificates in the right directory? Did you setup all 3 of them including the trust-store? Are all passwords correct?

Comment: My guess is that because you are using a self-signed certificate that it is giving you a warning because it's not trusted. If you are accessing with the browser can you click and create an exception?